# Error while using react-jsonschema-form with material in typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-jsonschema-forms

I am using react-jsonschema-form package with React, Material UI and Typescript. I am using the Material UI themed form called MuiForm5. I get compilation error for using this form and I am not able to resolve this. I am new to all these technologies. Any help is appreciated.

Giving here my code snipper, package dependencies and error.

I am following the documentation form this site https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation and material UI specific documentation from here
https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/tree/master/packages/material-ui

### App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { MuiForm5 as Form } from "@rjsf/material-ui";
import { JSONSchema7 } from "json-schema";

const schema: JSONSchema7 = {
  title: "Todo",
  type: "object",
  required: ["title"],
  properties: {
    title: { type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task" },
    done: { type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false },
  },
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Form
        schema={schema}
        onChange={({ formData }) =>
          console.log("change", JSON.stringify(formData))
        }
        onSubmit={({ formData }) =>
          console.log("submit", JSON.stringify(formData))
        }
        onError={({ errors }) => console.log("error", JSON.stringify(errors))}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Dependencies in package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.1",
    "@rjsf/core": "^4.1.1",
    "@rjsf/material-ui": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.44",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.15",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "@types/react-jsonschema-form": "^1.7.8"
  }
}
```

### Compilation error:

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:19:8
TS2786: 'Form' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<FormProps<any>, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<FormProps<any>, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<FormProps<any>, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/jayantwalvekar/Development/tests/my-jsonforms-app/node_modules/@types/react-transition-group/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    17 |   return (
    18 |     <div className='App'>
  > 19 |       <Form
       |        ^^^^
    20 |         schema={schema}
    21 |         uiSchema={{}}
    22 |         onChange={({ formData }) =>
```

Comment: same here, without using material ui . I am using the core form

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`//@ts-ignore` ing the error works for me.
i think that works because @rjsf/material-ui still uses class based component instead of functiona commponent

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you need to install @rjsf/utils

**package.json**

```
{
....    
"dependencies": {
.....
"@rjsf/utils": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
...

}
}
```

and pass the validator to the form

```
import validator from '@rjsf/validator-ajv6';

.....

<Form
 ....
 validator={validator}
... 
/>
```

Comment: your input is valid for @rjsf@5 and not @rjsf@4 the question is about.